# How to set the DefaultRoute to another Route in React Router

Tags: javascript, routes, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have the following:

```
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="dashboards" path="dashboards" handler={Dashboard}>
      <Route name="exploreDashboard" path="exploreDashboard" handler={ExploreDashboard} />
      <Route name="searchDashboard" path="searchDashboard" handler={SearchDashboard} />
      <DefaultRoute handler={DashboardExplain} />
    </Route>
    <DefaultRoute handler={SearchDashboard} />
  </Route>
```

When using the DefaultRoute, SearchDashboard renders incorrectly since any *Dashboard needs to rendered within Dashboard.

I would like for my DefaultRoute within the "app" Route to point to the Route "searchDashboard". Is this something that I can do with React Router, or should I use normal Javascript (for a page redirect) for this?

Basically, if the user goes to the home page I want to send them instead to the search dashboard. So I guess I'm looking for a React Router feature equivalent to `window.location.replace("mygreathostname.com/#/dashboards/searchDashboard");`

Comment: Have your tried of using Redirect instead of DefaultRoute ?<Redirect from="/" to="searchDashboard" />

Comment: @JonatanLundqvistMedén that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Write it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can use Redirect instead of DefaultRoute

```
<Redirect from="/" to="searchDashboard" />
```

Update 2019-08-09 to avoid problem with refresh use this instead, thanks to Ogglas

```
<Redirect exact from="/" to="searchDashboard" />
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43958016/3850405

Comment: is it just me, or when using this to hit a deep url directly, I always get redirected to the "to" url, instead of the route I'm trying to hit?

Comment: Should be noticed that if you are doing some redirection like `from='/a' to='/a/:id'`, you will need to use `<Switch>` to include your `<Redirect>` and `<Route>` component from react-router. Details see [doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dc2149ec0c63bfc95b71e40c81431e34cfbfeda9/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#from-string)

Comment: @Kulbear I had the same problem.  Doing what Ogglas said in his answer worked.

Comment: To make it work you most likely need to put this route last or do this `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/adaptation" />`

Comment: It's easy to oversee it, so I repeat: The important part of DarkWalker's Redirect rule is the `exact` flag. The acceptet answer is missing that, so it matches [almost] any route.

Comment: Redirect has been removed from React Router Dom

Answer (score 95):

**Update for version 6.4.5 to 6.8.1 <:**

Use `replace={true}` for `Navigate` component.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/searchDashboard" replace={true} />}>
    <Route path="searchDashboard" element={<SearchDashboard/>} />
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={<Navigate to="/" replace={true} />}
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.5/components/navigate
https://reactrouter.com/en/6.8.1/components/navigate

Thanks to @vicky for pointing this out in comments.

**Update:**

For v6 you can do it like this with `Navigate`. You can use a "No Match" Route to handle "no match" cases.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/searchDashboard" />}>
    <Route path="searchDashboard" element={<SearchDashboard/>} />
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={<Navigate to="/" />}
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69872699/3850405

**Original:**

The problem with using `<Redirect from="/" to="searchDashboard" />` is if you have a different URL, say `/indexDashboard` and the user hits refresh or gets a URL sent to them, the user will be redirected to `/searchDashboard` anyway.

If you wan't users to be able to refresh the site or send URLs use this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
    <Redirect to="/searchDashboard"/>
)}/>
```

Use this if `searchDashboard` is behind login:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/searchDashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login"/>
  )
)}/>
```

Comment: It should be use replace in navigate otherwise there should be back event not work.  <Route path='/' element={<Navigate replace to="appointments-history" />}/>

Comment: @vicky Updated the answer with `replace={true}`

Comment: Just FYI your update for `react-router@6` is incorrect, this code won't work. `Navigate` doesn't render an `Outlet` so none of the nested routes are reachable.

Answer (score 38):

I was incorrectly trying to create a default path with:

```
<IndexRoute component={DefaultComponent} />
<Route path="/default-path" component={DefaultComponent} />
```

But this creates two different paths that render the same component. Not only is this pointless, but it can cause glitches in your UI, i.e., when you are styling `<Link/>` elements based on `this.history.isActive()`.

The right way to create a default route (that is not the index route) is to use `<IndexRedirect/>`:

```
<IndexRedirect to="/default-path" />
<Route path="/default-path" component={DefaultComponent} />
```

This is based on react-router 1.0.0. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/IndexRedirect.js.

Comment: What's the point of having a `Route` to something that is already handled by your `IndexRoute`?

Comment: There is no point, and I edited my answer to make it clear I was not advocating that.

Comment: This is what I've been doing as well, but I'd love a solution that serves up a component (my homepage) at `/` instead of having to redirect to e.g. `/home`.

Comment: Looks like I'm looking for `<IndexRoute>` after all. Sorry for the noise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706913/react-router-what-is-the-purpose-of-indexroute https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-routes

Answer (score 14):

Since V6 was released recently, the accepted answer won't work since Redirect no more exists in V6. Consider using Navigate.

```
 <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/searchDashboard" />} />
```

Ref:-  [V6 docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate)

Answer (score 13):

2020:

Instead of using *Redirect*, simply add multiple routes in the `path`.

Example:

```
<Route exact path={["/","/defaultPath"]} component={searchDashboard} />
```

**UPDATE 2023**

This doesn't work in v6, so use this instead

```
<Route exact path="/" element={searchDashboard} />
<Route exact path="/defaultPath" element={searchDashboard} />
```

Comment: Hey are you sure there are square brackets there? Because I was getting the error: ```"Uncaught TypeError: meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function" ```
so when I removed the square brackets, it works fine, like this: 
```<Route exact path={"/","/defaultPath"} component={searchDashboard} />```

Answer (score 12):

Jonathan's answer didn't seem to work for me. I'm using React v0.14.0 and React Router v1.0.0-rc3. This did:

`<IndexRoute component={Home}/>`.

So in Matthew's Case, I believe he'd want:

`<IndexRoute component={SearchDashboard}/>`.

Source: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ComponentLifecycle.md

Comment: Thanks for the share. I was using React v0.13 and the version of React-Router for that, so a pre-1.0/rc version. Hope this helps others!

Comment: I think this makes you lose the context. `SearchDashboard` will be the component you will see when you arrive at the homepage, but not the `Dashboard` component that is wrapping it if you go directly to `/dashboard/searchDashboard`. React-router dynamically builds up a hierarchy of nested components based on the routes matched by the URL, so I think you really do need a redirect here.

Answer (score 8):

**May 2022**

1. Import `Navigate`

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

2. Add

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
```

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
            <Route path='home' element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path='login' element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

3. Done!

Answer (score 7):

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path='/'>
          <Redirect to="/something" />
        </Route>
//rest of code here
```

this will make it so that when you load up the server on local host it will re direct you to /something

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue; I wanted a default route handler if none of the route handler matched.

My solutions is to use a wildcard as the path value. ie
Also make sure it is the last entry in your routes definition.

```
<Route path="/" component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
    <Route path="home" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="*" component={HomePage} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 4):

For those coming into 2017, this is the new solution with `IndexRedirect`:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/welcome" />
  <Route path="welcome" component={Welcome} />
  <Route path="about" component={About} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="dashboards" path="dashboards" handler={Dashboard}>
      <Route name="exploreDashboard" path="exploreDashboard" handler={ExploreDashboard} />
      <Route name="searchDashboard" path="searchDashboard" handler={SearchDashboard} />
      <DefaultRoute handler={DashboardExplain} />
    </Route>
    <Redirect from="/*" to="/" />
  </Route>
```

Comment: What is equivalent of `DefaultRoute` in `react-router` v4?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I think it is: `<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>` . https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method is to use the react router [IndexRoutes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md) component

You use it like this (taken from the react router docs linked above):

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to="/welcome" />
    <Route path="welcome" component={Welcome} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
</Route>
```

Comment: The linked page is giving 404 now

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to install:

```
npm install react-router-dom;
```

Then you need to use your *App.js* (in your case it can be different) and do the modification below.
In this case I selected the *Redirect* to get proper rendering process.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Redirect to="/Home" component={Routes.HomePage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/Biz" component={Routes.Biz} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
```

If you successfully do the modification above, you can see the redirect URL is on your browser path and rendering process also working properly according to their component.

*Some time ago, we had an opportunity to use the component named "DefaultRoute" in the react routing.*

Now, it's a deprecated method, and it’s not so popular to use it. You can create the custom route named default or whatever, but still, it’s not how we do it in modern React.js development.

It’s just because using the "DefaultRoute" route, we can cause some rendering problems, and it's the thing that we definitely would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it-

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    <TabBar />
    <div className="content">
      <Route exact path={["/default", "/"]}> //Imp
        <DefStuff />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/otherpage">
        <Otherstuff />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/defult" /> //Imp
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/expenses" />} />
```

In context:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<App />}>
      <Route path="/expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
      <Route path="/invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/expenses" />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use it like this to redirect on a particular URL and render component after redirecting from old-router to new-router.

```
<Route path="/old-router">
  <Redirect exact to="/new-router"/>
  <Route path="/new-router" component={NewRouterType}/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code after all the exact routes. If none of them matches the current route, it'll render the default route.

```
<Route path="*" element={<DefaultComponent />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to */Home* when user goes to */* (default Route):

```
 <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/Home" />} />
```

Use the Navigate element to redirect the user to */Home* every time they go to the */* route.