# React-Router : What is the purpose of IndexRoute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I don't understand what the purpose of using an **IndexRoute** and **IndexLink**. It seems that in any case the code below would have selected the Home component first unless the About path was activated.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="about" component={About}/>
</Route>
```

vs

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="about" component={About}/>
</Route>
```

What's the advantage/purpose here of the first case?

Comment: Why would `Home` be chosen in the first example, unless the path was `/home`? Check out the explanation in the docs: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/IndexRoutes.md

Comment: You can imagine that main is a navigation bar and that Home and About are the main page that you can click through on the navigation bar.

Comment: In the top example, going to `/` would render `App` with `Home` passed as a child. In the bottom example, going to `/` would render `App` with *neither* `Home` or `About` being rendered, since neither of their paths match.

Comment: Ohh!!! Could you put that as an answer so I can give you credit? Thank you!

Comment: In the change from v0.13 to v1.0 they changed the name from `DefaultRoute` to `IndexRoute`. I find that 'default' better describes the purpose. https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#linking-to-defaultindex-routes

Answer (score 114, accepted):

In the top example, going to `/` would render `App` with `Home` passed as a child. In the bottom example, going to `/` would render `App` with *neither* `Home` nor `About` being rendered, since neither of their paths match.

For older versions of React Router, more information is available on associated version's [Index Routes and Index Links page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/5e69b23a369b7dbcb9afc6cdca9bf2dcf07ad432/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md). Starting in version 4.0, React Router no longer uses the `IndexRoute` abstraction to achieve the same goal.

Comment: So what could we using this feature in practice?

Comment: For instance, we can create one parent container, several child routes, and set one of these child routes as default (IndexRoute). Or, if we do not need a default child route, and need to hint the user that he is to choose something (no IndexRoute then)

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor Thanks, I've updated the second half of the answer

Comment: what passed as a child means exactly? loading on the background? being able to access props? other?