# What's the Difference between the React Router v4 Router Types?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have tried to learn some React basics on YouTube and from the official docs and I encountered multiple different Routers in only two videos. Sadly, the instructor did not explain anything at all and I'm even more confused than I was before.

dr: I really don't get the difference between a browser router, a 'normal' router and an index router. Thanks everyone for helping me.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Browser Router [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

> A `Router` that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

### Route [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

> Its most basic responsibility is to render some UI when a location matches the route’s path.

### What the heck does that stuff mean

`BrowserRouter` is a React Component that watches the URL and more or less passes the current path down to its children, while a `Route` component will render some other component based on the URL information passed to it by its parent `BrowserRouter`.  `IndexRoute` is used to set a default view when rendering a specific `Route` Component.  For more on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706913/react-router-what-is-the-purpose-of-indexroute).

Remember, `react-router` is just a set of cleverly implemented vanilla react components that can be used to simulate a server-ish side route handler, which in turn makes a Single Page App appear to be multiple pages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but what is the difference between `<Router />` and `<BrowserRoute />`?