# Highlight default link in react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm creating a simple sidebar for when someone visits a root directory of site.com/,

```
Test
Test2
```

When I click on either, it loads their components on the side and the link becomes highlighted.

for now I'm using a Route for / to load the Test Component by default.

my question is, how do I get the Test link highlighted by default when one goes to /?

```
<Router>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to="/test" activeClassName="active">Test</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/test2" activeClassName="active">Test2</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <aside>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Test} />
          <Route path="/test" exact={true} component={Test} />
          <Route path="/test2" exact={true} component={Test2} />   
        </Switch>
      </aside>
    </section>
</Router>
```

is there another way of setting the default component?

Comment: linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29552601/104380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both the component rendered at `/` and `/test` are same, you could simply redirect from `/` to `/test` in which case your NavLink will highlight correctly

```
<Router>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to="/test" activeClassName="active">Test</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/test2" activeClassName="active">Test2</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <aside>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/test" component={Test} />
          <Route path="/test" exact={true} component={Test} />
          <Route path="/test2" exact={true} component={Test2} />   
        </Switch>
      </aside>
    </section>
</Router>
```