# How to make default route in ReactJS for child route concept

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two routes like below

```
            <Route path='/dashboard/home' exact component={Charts} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/map-view' component={Mapview} />
```

If user is navigating to just '/dashboard' also I need to show '/dashboard/home' route. Whenever I click home also I need to show same. How can I make it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the DefaultRoute to another Route in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552601/how-to-set-the-defaultroute-to-another-route-in-react-router)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect):

```
<Redirect from='/dashboard' to='/dashboard/home'/>
```

Comment: If I add like this, For second route click also its navigating to /dashboard/home

Comment: Then do this: `<Route exact path='/dashboard' render={() => (
    <Redirect to='/dashboard/home'/>
)}/>`