# How can I redirect in React Router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to upgrade to React Router v6 (`react-router-dom 6.0.1`).

Here is my updated code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/lab" element={<Lab />} />
    <Route render={() => <Navigate to="/" />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The last `Route` is redirecting the rest of paths to `/`.

However, I got an error

> TS2322: Type '{ render: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.   Property 'render' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.

However, based on [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-redirects-inside-switch), it does have `render` for `Route`. How can I use it correctly?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the docs. Notice how [right in the section above that](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v51) they deprecated `render` in favour of `children`? But it looks like that section you were reading talks about upgrading from v5 to v5.1, they only removed `render` in v6. Looks like [`<Route element={<Navigate to="/" />} />` is the new style](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mjackson/b5748add2795ce7448a366ae8f8ae3bb#not-server-rendering

Comment: Also from https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f#get-started-upgrading-today: "*When you finally do upgrade to v6, convert `<Route render={() => ...}>` to `<Route element={...}>` and you're done.*"

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I succeed by a little updates: `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />`, feel free to post as an answer!

Answer (score 372, accepted):

I think you should use the no match route approach.

Check this in the documentation: *[Adding a "No Match" Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route)*

```
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/lab" element={<Lab />} />
    <Route
        path="*"
        element={<Navigate to="/" replace />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

To keep the history clean, you should set `replace` prop. This will avoid extra redirects after the user click back.

Comment: If you want to redirect outside react components or without hooks, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/1494454).

Comment: What if `/` is a parent route to those others? How do you prevent `/` itself from being a route that can be navigated to? And instead redirect `/` to say `/home` when `home` is a child under `/`?

Comment: Worth noting that this has no SSR support for static routing 

Comment: @RodolfoSilva but what if we also want to add a NotFound Page than what path we will add to the NotFound ?

Comment: @KashifAli in that case, you should replace the Navigation componet with you custom Not Found screen. I don't think you will be able to have both using a wildcard path. But you can use a Nested approach to limit when the user should be redirected inside some path.

Comment: Is there any api docs on Navigate and replace?

It seems that i should have stopped with the docs, but somehow ended here.

Answer (score 77):

I found another way to do this:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
let navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
   if (LoggedIn){
      return navigate("/");
   }
},[LoggedIn]);
```

See *[Overview, Navigation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/overview#navigation)*.

Comment: It says useNavigator can be used only in the context of the router. It can't be used alone.

Comment: use this component inside an appropriate Router component: example: <BrowserRouter>{...your routes here, which in turn reference the component in this answer}</BrowserRouter>

Answer (score 18):

Create the file RequireAuth.tsx

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/Auth";

export function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  let { user } = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  } else {
    return children;
  }
}
```

Import the component to need user a private router:

```
import { Routes as Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { RequireAuth } from "./RequireAuth";
import { SignIn } from "../pages/SignIn";
import { Dashboard } from "../pages/Dashboard";

export function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route
        path="/dashboard"
        element={
          <RequireAuth>
            <Dashboard />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In version 5 of React, i.e., *react-router-dom*, we had the Redirect component. But in version 6 of React it is updated to the Navigate  components.

We can pass replace in these components to avoid unnecessary redirects on clicking back and forward option.

Demonstration for usage is attached below:

```
<Route path="/" element={user ? <Home /> : <Register />} />
<Route path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Login />} />
<Route path="/register" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Register />} />
```

Answer (score 8):

**FOR react-router VERSION 6**

**New example after editing----->**(more simple easy to read)

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../NavbarCompo/About';
import Contact from '../NavbarCompo/Contact';
import About from '../NavbarCompo/About';
import Login  from '../NavbarCompo/Login';
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar';
import Error from '../pages/error';
import Products  from '../pages/products';
import Data from '../NavbarCompo/Data';

const Roter=()=>{
    return (
    <Router>

            <Navbar />
        <Routes>
            
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<Products />} />
            <Route path='/data' element={<Data />} />
            <Route path ='*' element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>


    </Router>
    )
}
export default Roter;
```

**Look at the example**

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./compo/form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Route,Routes,Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Form />
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    element: <h1>hola amigo,you are in about section</h1>
  },
  {
    path:"*",
    element:<Navigate to="/" replace />
  }
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**check this out**
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview

Comment: I mean for react-router v6  ,check this out https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview

Answer (score 5):

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const component =()=>{

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handelGoToLogin = () => {
        navigate('/auth/login')
    }

    return(<>
        //.........
    
        <Button onClick={handelGoToLogin} variant="outlined" color="primary" size="large" fullWidth>
             Back
        </Button>

    </>)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route index element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the issue of redirecting the user to /login if the user tries to access the dashboard without login .First I use the

`Navigate('/login')`

but it's not the correct way as it render the page first and then redirects to login so then I used another approach which is as follow.

```
    const auth  = useContext(AuthContext);

if(!auth?.loggedin){
  
    return <Navigate to='/login'></Navigate>
}return children;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Navigate component from **react-router-dom** to achieve the same effect as Redirect. First, `import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'` Here's an example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/todos" replace />} />
```

The **replace** is used to replace the current history entry instead of adding a new entry.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
const [login, setLogin] = useState(true)
return (<>
{!login && <Navigate to="/login" />}
<>)
```

Answer (score 1):

In React Router v6, we can use `<Navigate />` like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69872699/8915198) to redirect.

However, in that case, if we have used params/slug for example `/users/:id` in the path then it will redirect from `/users/10` to `/new-path/:id` instead of `/new-path/10`.

To resolve such cases, we can have a custom component like below:

```
// Redirect.tsx

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { generatePath, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function Redirect({ to }: { to: string }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const params = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(generatePath(to, params), { replace: true })
  })

  return null
}

export default Redirect
```

And we can import it like:

```
<Route path="/users/:id" element={<Redirect to="/new-path/:id" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For class components, at the first you should make a functional component, and then use HOC technical to use useNavigate [React hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#React_hooks).

Like this:

#### File *withrouter.js*

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
    return (<WrappedComponent {...props} navigate={useNavigate()}/>);
};
```

Then use it in other class components like this:

```
export default withRouter(Signin);
```

And use props for redirect like this:

```
this.props.navigate('/');
```

Answer (score -1):

For `react-router-dom` version 5.3 I used `useHistory()`.

Sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const redirectToOverview = () => {
    // Use the history.push method to navigate to /app/overview
    history.push('/app/overview');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* When this button is clicked, redirectToOverview will be called */}
      <button onClick={redirectToOverview}>Go to Overview</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: That is not a redirect from one route to another. That is just standard navigation.