# react router v6 navigate outside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In react-router v5 i created history object like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

And then passed it to the Router:

```
import { Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Router history={history}>
 ... my routes
</Router>
```

I did it for the opportunity to usage history outside of component:

```
   // store action
    logout() {
        this.user = null;
        history.push('/');
    }
```

This way I moved the logic to the store and the components were kept as clean as possible. But now, in react router v6 i cant do the same. I can still navigate using `useNavigate()` inside my component, but i cannot create a `navigate` to use its into my store. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Comment: @ColdAtNight thanks, but it is not specified there how to unage ```navigate``` outside of component. And that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, it turns out you *can* duplicate the behavior if you implement a custom router that instantiates the history state in the same manner as RRDv6 routers.

Examine the [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/e4f663cec9f79150933127e53c7fdacf87eaab6e/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L734-L775) implementation for example:

> ```
> export function BrowserRouter({
>   basename,
>   children,
>   window
> }: BrowserRouterProps) {
>   let historyRef = React.useRef<BrowserHistory>();
>   if (historyRef.current == null) {
>     historyRef.current = createBrowserHistory({ window });
>   }
>
>   let history = historyRef.current;
>   let [state, setState] = React.useState({
>     action: history.action,
>     location: history.location
>   });
>
>   React.useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
>
>   return (
>     <Router
>       basename={basename}
>       children={children}
>       location={state.location}
>       navigationType={state.action}
>       navigator={history}
>     />
>   );
> }
> ```

Create a `CustomRouter` that consumes a custom `history` object and manages the state:

```
const CustomRouter = ({ history, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);

  return (
    <Router
      {...props}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action}
      navigator={history}
    />
  );
};
```

This effectively proxies the custom `history` object into the `Router` and manages the navigation state.

From here you swap in the `CustomRouter` with custom `history` object for the existing `Router` imported from `react-router-dom`.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <CustomRouter history={history}>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </CustomRouter>
  );
}
```

Fork of your codesandbox:

[image: Edit react-router-v6-navigate-outside-of-components]

### Update

`react-router-dom@6` surfaces a history router.

[HistoryRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/e4f663cec9f79150933127e53c7fdacf87eaab6e/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L835-L879)

> `<unstable_HistoryRouter>` takes an instance of the [`history`](https://github.com/remix-run/history) library as
> prop. This allows you to use that instance in non-React contexts or as
> a global variable.
>
> ```
> import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
> import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
>
> const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <HistoryRouter history={history}>
>     {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
>   </HistoryRouter>,
>   root
> );
> ```

There is this note:

> This API is currently prefixed as `unstable_` because you may
> unintentionally add two versions of the `history` library to your app,
> the one you have added to your package.json and whatever version React
> Router uses internally. If it is allowed by your tooling, it's
> recommended to not add `history` as a direct dependency and instead
> rely on the nested dependency from the `react-router` package. Once we
> have a mechanism to detect mis-matched versions, this API will remove
> its `unstable_` prefix.

### Notes on RRDv6.4+

If you are using RRDv6.4+ and *not* using the Data routers the good-ish news is that `unstable_HistoryRouter` is still being [exported](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L357-L386) through at least RRDv6.7.0. You can follow along the filed issue in the repo [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9422#issuecomment-1301182219).

If you are using the Data routers then the new "unstable" method is to use an attached `navigate` function from the router object directly.

Example:

```js
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter(...);

...

router.navigate(targetPath, options);
```

Comment: What would the CustomRouter look like in typescript?

Comment: also, if I'm only interested in replacing <Router history={history}>{children}</Router> then do I need  {...props}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action} or do I only pass history?

Comment: @cldev `react-router-dom` is written in Typescript, you could likely lift the types from [source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L126-L162). For second question, the code in my answer is the minimum required. The [Router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L237-L244) requires the `location` and `navigator` props, the rest are optional.

Comment: That's very useful, thank you. I get an error on navigationType in my return saying: Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Action | undefined'.
  Type '"PUSH"' is not assignable to type 'Action | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(99, 5): The expected type comes from property 'navigationType' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProps'.   So I'm wondering if I need to add a type? But then location doesn't error.

Comment: @cldev I'll be honest, I'm minimally versed in Typescript. You'd be much better off asking a new question on SO with appropriate tags. New posts garner more attention than comments on a months old answer.

Comment: Looks like unstable_HistoryRouter has been removed in the latest version :-(

Comment: @ChambreNoire Yeah, the `HistoryRouter` was unfortunately removed in RRDv6.4 with the introduction of their new Data APIs and revamp of their contexts. It's going to make using RRD with Redux (*i.e. [redux-first-history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-first-history)*) a little more interesting/difficult/impossible.

Comment: @DrewReese strange as this seems like a pretty common use-case to me...

Comment: @ChambreNoire Yeah, quite the bummer if you ask me. On one hand it makes sense RRD is moving towards fetching data when a route loads, but it seems they are moving in on territory `redux-toolkit/query` already handles and handles quite nicely... at the expense of being able to issue imperative navigation actions from elsewhere in the app outside the router/react code, i.e. asynchronous actions. I don't fully understand the impetus here on RRD maintainers' part.

Comment: @DrewReese yup plus it doesn't look like they have an official stance on how to achieve this now (unless my google-fu is lacking). kinda looks like they are just washing their hands of the issue :-(

Comment: I get a typescript error for `window` on `const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });`

Comment: @FiddleFreak `window` is of type `Window`. See [docs](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#createbrowserhistory) and [source](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/packages/history/index.ts#L355).

Answer (score 8):

More simpler code (`react-router-dom@6.15.0`), I did like this

1- create a browser router Object `router.tsx` :

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
  {
    path: 'page',
    element: <SomePage />,
  }
]);
export default router;
```

2- Then in the `App.tsx` (or where you want to use the router):

```
import {  RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import router from '@/router';

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

3- now to navigate from outside the components

```
import router from '@/router';
...
router.navigate('/path-to-go');
```

Comment: But please make sure that it doesn't lead to circular dependencies! Otherwise, you'll shoot yourself in a knee like I did

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript solution of accepted answer

history object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

export default customHistory;
```

BrowserRouterProps is a react-router type.

> ```
> export interface BrowserRouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   window?: Window;
> }
> ```

CustomRouter:

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouterProps, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserHistory } from "history";
import customHistory from "./history";
interface Props extends BrowserRouterProps {
  history: BrowserHistory;
}
export const CustomRouter = ({ basename, history, children }: Props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location,
  });
  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);
  return (
    <Router
      navigator={customHistory}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action}
      children={children}
      basename={basename}
    />
  );
};
```

use CustomRouter instead BrowserRouter

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CustomRouter history={customHistory}>
      <App />
    </CustomRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: There error in TypeScript

Comment: typescript error `Module '"history"' has no exported member 'BrowserHistory'`

Answer (score 3):

### Typescript solution with HistoryRouter from react-router-dom

Different from other answers, this solution uses the HistoryRouter imported from react-router-dom and using TypeScript.

#### 1. Create a new file with your CustomRouter component. I'm placing it at *"./components/CustomRouter.tsx"* in this example.

```
import React, { FC, PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });

const CustomRouter: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    return (
    <HistoryRouter history={history} {...props}>
        {children}
    </HistoryRouter>
    );
};

export const rootNavigate = (to: string) => {
    history.push(to);
};

export default CustomRouter;
```

#### 2. Import the CustomRouter and use it in place of the BrowserRouter

```
[...]
import CustomRouter from "./components/CustomRouter";
[...]
ReactDOM.render(
    <CustomRouter>
    [...]
    </CustomRouter>,
    root
);
```

#### 3. Import and use "rootNavigate" anyware to navigate.

```
import { rootNavigate } from "../components/CustomRouter";

function doAnything() {
    alert("Ok, will do");
    rootNavigate("/anywhere-you-want");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic solution. You saved my day! By the way, I believe that the developers of react router dom are overcomplicating things. A very easy thing ("call a function to navigate to a route") needs a custom router. Seriously? In any library that has the concept of "routes" should have a "navigate(path)" function as a built-in primitive.

Comment: I get two typescript errors... #1 `window` on `const history = createBrowserHistory({ window });` and #2 `Property 'encodeLocation' is missing in type 'History<unknown>' but required in type 'History'`

Answer (score 2):

Below approach worked for me, using HistoryRouter (React Router v6):

```js
//1.
//create some file like HistoryRouterObject.ts, which will return the history
//object from anywhere
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const historyObject = createBrowserHistory({ window });
export default historyObject;



//2.
//in your index.tsx, wrap your components with HistoryRouter and pass it the 
//historyObject above 
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import historyObject from './somewhere in your app/HistoryRouterObject'

root.render(
<HistoryRouter history={historyObject}>
      //your components and Routers ...
</HistoryRouter>
);



//3.
//now  you can use the history object in any non-react component function, like IsUserAuthenticated.ts, 

import historyObject from './somewhere in your app/HistoryRouterObject'

function xyz(){
historyObject.replace('/');
//or
historyObject.push("/");
}
```

Comment: I get two typescript errors... #1 `window` on `const historyObject = createBrowserHistory({ window });` and #2 `Property 'encodeLocation' is missing in type 'History<unknown>' but required in type 'History'`

Answer (score 2):

**React Router Dom 6.5**

1. Set up your routes with createBrowserRouter

   ```
   import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

   const router = createBrowserRouter([
       {
         path: "/",
         element: <Root />,
         children: [
           {
             path: "children",
             element: <Children />,
           },
         ]
       }
    ])
   ```
2. import the router and use its navigate property method to redirect with your designated path

   ```
    import router from "@router/index";

    router.navigate("/auth/login");
   ```

Comment: This is a big hack using a private api, but it does work.

Comment: why sir Brandon

Comment: `router.navigator` has two types of argument that it receives. As long as you are not providing a number as an argument to `router.navigator` method, it seems fine to use it.

Answer (score 1):

React Router 6 has a redirect component method you can use here:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect

Answer (score 0):

1. Install history:

```
yarn add history
```

2. Create a `history.ts` (or js) file:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

3. Replace your BrowserRouter to a HistoryRouter from unstable_HistoryRouter, using your history as argument:

```
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {history} from './history';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HistoryRouter history={history}>
       ...
    </HistoryRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

4. Now you can navigate outside React Components (ts or js files):

```
import { history } from './history';
...
history.push('/');
```

Comment: I'm getting a typescript error for the `history` on the left side of the equals. `Property 'encodeLocation' is missing in type 'BrowserHistory' but required in type 'History'`