# Pass Data between classes components (React)

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and web dev in general. I need to pass a few values from a class to another when switching pages. My routes and links are working just fine.
I've tried a lot of stuff but I can't manage to pass the data to the class that is going to render the next page on the website. I need your help please ! (feel free to give me advice about the code, it's probably pretty shitty lol)

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css'
import SignIn from './SignIn/SignIn';
import Register from './Register/Register';
import Informations from './Register/Informations/Informations';
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound/error';
import Photos from './Register/Informations/Photos/Photos'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Register/>} exact/>
                <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
                <Route path='/sign-in' element={<SignIn/>}/>
                <Route path='/infos' element={<Informations/>}/>
                <Route path='/photos' element={<Photos/>}/>
                <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
}

export default App
```

Register.jsx (starting point of the site, I want the data to go from this class to the next one)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Register.scss'
import axios from 'axios'
import test_img from '../blink_logo.svg';

class Register extends Component
{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =
        {
            email: '',
            firstname: '',
            lastname: '',
            telephone: '',
            password: ''
        }
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    }

    handleLogin () {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user/',  {email: this.state.email,
                                                                                                        firstname: this.state.firstname,
                                                                                                        lastname: this.state.lastname,
                                                                                                        telephone: this.state.telephone,
                                                                                                        password: this.state.password})
        .then((response) =>
        {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({username: response.data.username})
        }).catch(error =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        })
        console.log("Email: " + this.state.email);
    console.log("Firstname: " + this.state.firstname);
    console.log("Lastname: " + this.state.lastname);
    console.log("Telephone: " + this.state.telephone);
    console.log("Password: " + this.state.password);
    }
    handleEmailChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }
    handleFirstnameChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({firstname: e.target.value});
    }
    handleLastnameChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({lastname: e.target.value});
    }
    handleTelephoneChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({telephone: e.target.value});
    }
    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value});
    }

    render () {
        return (
                <div>
                        <div className='image'>
                            <   img src={test_img} alt="Blink Logo"/>
                        </div>
                <div className='base-container-register'>
            <div className='header'>Rejoindre l'aventure !</div>
                    <div className='content'>
                            <div className='form'>
                                <div className='label'>Email</div>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                                </div>
                                <div className='label'>Prénom</div>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="prénom" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleFirstnameChange} />
                                </div>
                                <div className='label'>Nom</div>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="nom" value={this.state.lastname} onChange={this.handleLastnameChange} />
                                </div>
                                <div className='label'>Mot de passe</div>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="mot de passe" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className='label'>Numéro de téléphone</div>
                                <div className='form-group'>
                                    <input type="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="numéro de téléphone" value={this.state.telephone} onChange={this.handleTelephoneChange}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div className='footer' >
                            <Link to='/infos' state={{email: this.state.email}}>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLogin} className='footer'>Se lancer</button>
                            </Link>
                            {/* <Link to='/infos' params={email: this.state.email}>
                                <button onClick={this.handleLogin} className='footer'>Se lancer</button>
                            </Link> */}
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div className='redirect-to-signin'> Vous avez déjà un compte ? &nbsp;&nbsp;<Link to='/sign-in'>Sign in</Link> </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register
```

Informations.jsx (where I want to grab the data from Register)

```
class Informations extends Component
{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =
        {
            username: '',
            workInfo: '',
            webSite: '',
            socialId: '',
            file: null,
            file_name: '...'
        }
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.handlePhotoChange = this.handlePhotoChange.bind(this)

    }
```

I'm using react-router-dom v6.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use route state to send data from one component to another when navigating from one component to another. What "data" are you trying/wanting to send from `Register` to `Informations`? How are you navigating from `"/register"` to `"/infos"`? See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902006/8690857) for using RRDv6 with class components.

Answer (score 0):

When calling your Informations class just pass the values you want to send, as parameters.

```
<Informations value1={4} value2={8} />
```

To get the data you are sending from inside the Informations class:

```
this.props.value1
```

Answer (score 0):

With v6 of `react-router-dom`, we can pass props to our components using the following method:

```
<Route path='/infos' element={<Informations value1={4} value2={8} />}/>
```

However, you are suggesting that values from the `Register` component need to make their way over to the `Informations` component.  The better method for passing those values around would be to take advantage of [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Using Context, you could have some state defined in a custom context that you can set in `Register`, and read in `Informations`.