# "withRouter" not exported from react-router-dom in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-router-dom

I'm relatively new to Typescript and React.

Following tutorials, I'm trying to add `withRouter` from `"react-router-dom"`, but I'm getting an error saying `Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'withRouter'.`

There is no reference to `withRouter` anywhere in the react-router-dom node-modules package. This is confusing to me and I don't know if typescript is the origin of the missing function. I know they have removed some functionality but I can't find anything that could replace it, in order to access `this.props.history.push()` from inside my component.

Can anyone advise on this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `react-router-dom` version?

Comment: The duplicate explains what happened to `withRouter`. To address the history issue you'll need to convert class components to function components so you can use the `useNavigate` hook, or create a custom `withRouter` HOC replacement and pass in the `navigate` function which replaced the `history` object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899955/problem-in-redirecting-programmatically-to-a-route-in-react-router-v6/69902006#69902006

Answer (score 2):

what version of `react-router-dom` are you using? looks like `withRouter` isn't supported anymore.
For v6 it has been replaced with hooks. See [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/48b7c60a2133a617d64533b54eb299dbd2d1be0e/docs/faq.md#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) for the explanation from their docs, there is also a bit [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/5730e28a7472e3a1b967d95c5c4cc643c570d5c7/docs/upgrading/v5.md#:%7E:text=Along%20with%20the%20upgrade%20to%20v5.1%2C%20you%20should%20replace%20any%20usage%20of%20withRouter%20with%20hooks.%20You%20should%20also%20get%20rid%20of%20any%20%22floating%22%20%3CRoute%3E%20elements%20that%20are%20not%20inside%20a%20%3CSwitch%3E.%20Again%2C%20the%20blog%20post%20about%20v5.1%20explains%20how%20to%20do%20this%20in%20greater%20detail.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll make the change to hooks so I can use this component.