# Why is `<Link>` not working in form submission in reactjs v.18, react router dom v6.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom, react-link

I will try to explain to the best where you can understand the issue.

If you see there is a button in both `AddContact.js` and `EditContact.js`, such as, `Add` button and `Update` button. They are wrapped by `<Link to="/"></Link>`. However, if I click on the button the event is not happening. If I comment the `<Link>` the event is being executed. I require both of my `event handler` and `<Link>` should work.

If you are going to comment or suggest me to put a event handler on button instead of `onSubmit` could you please explain why it is and why not it will work being the present way of code.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import api from "../api/contacts";
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import AddContact from './AddContact';
import EditContact from "./EditContact";
import ContactList from './ContactList';
import ContactDetail from './ContactDetail';

function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState("");
  const [editContactDetail, setEditContactDetail] = useState("");


  //Retrieve Contacts
  const retrieveContacts = async () => {
    const response = await api.get("contacts");
    return response.data;
  };

  const addContactHandler = async (singleContact) => {
    const addContact = {
      id: uuid(),
      ...singleContact
    };

  const addContactDone = await api.post("/contacts", addContact);
    setContacts([...contacts, addContactDone.data]);
  };

  const removeContactHandler = async (id) => {
        await api.delete(`/contacts/${id}`);
        const newContactList = contacts.filter((deleteContact) => {
        return deleteContact.id !== id;
     });
     setContacts(newContactList);
  };

  const searchHandler = (searchTerm) => {
      setSearchTerm(searchTerm);
      if (searchTerm !== "") {
        const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
            return Object.values(contact)
              .join(" ")
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        });
        setSearchResults(newContactList);
      } else {
        setSearchResults(contacts);
      }
  };

  const editChosenContact = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((editRecord) => {
      return editRecord.id === id;
    });
    setEditContactDetail(newContactList);
  };

  const updateContactPerson = async (selectedContactEdit) => {
    const editResponse = await api.put(`/contacts/${selectedContactEdit.id}`, selectedContactEdit);
    const {id, name, email} = editResponse.data;

    setContacts( contacts.map(contact => {
      return contact.id === id ? {...editResponse.data} : contact;
    })
    );
  };  

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllContacts = async () => {
      const allContacts = await retrieveContacts();
      if(allContacts) setContacts(allContacts);
    }
    getAllContacts();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect happening!");
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
          <Header/>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={ <ContactList contacts={ searchTerm.length < 1 ? contacts : searchResults } getContactId={ removeContactHandler } 
              getEditContact={editChosenContact} term={ searchTerm } searchKeyword={ searchHandler } />  }/>          
            <Route exact path="/add" element={ <AddContact addContactAction={ addContactHandler } />  }/>          
            <Route exact path="/edit/:id" element={ <EditContact editContactPerson={ editContactDetail } updateContactPerson={ updateContactPerson } />  }/>          
            <Route exact path="/contact/:id" element={ <ContactDetail /> }/>
          </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AddContact.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class AddContact extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name: "",
        email: ""
    }

    add = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.name === "" || this.state.email === "") {
            alert("Enter name and email!");
            return;
        }
        this.props.addContactAction(this.state);
        this.setState({ name: "", email: ""});
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={ this.add }>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-12 mt-5">
                            <h2>Add Contact</h2>
                        </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" placeholder="name" aria-label="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value}) }/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" className="form-control" placeholder="email" aria-label="email" value={this.state.email } onChange={ (e) => this.setState({email: e.target.value}) }/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-12 mt-3">
                                <Link to="/">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default AddContact;
```

EditContact.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";
import ContactDetail from "./ContactDetail";

class EditContact extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state =  { 
            id: props.editContactPerson[0].id,
            name: props.editContactPerson[0].name,
            email: props.editContactPerson[0].email
         };

    }
    update = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.name !== "" && this.state.email !== "") {
            this.props.updateContactPerson(this.state);
        } else {
            alert("All fields are mandatory!");
        }
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={ this.update }>

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-12 mt-5">
                            <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
                        </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" className="form-control" placeholder="name" aria-label="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={ (e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value}) }/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" className="form-control" placeholder="email" aria-label="email" value={this.state.email } onChange={ (e) => this.setState({email: e.target.value}) }/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-12 mt-3">
                                <Link to="/">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>                                
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default EditContact;
```

Comment: Why have you got a button in a link? Don't you just want a link _styled like_ a button? Or if that's to submit the form, _just a button_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Do you mean wrapping a button with a `<Link>` is not a right way of coding? If I do that way, the result is same, the event handler is not being executed but quickly redirected to home page since it is a `/`.

Comment: It's not going to lead to valid HTML (as an [`a`nchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) shouldn't contain interactive content) and you're asking because it doesn't work, so no.

Comment: Yes, I agree, `<Link>` is in turn a `<a></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue as I see it is that the click event from the `button` element propagates up to the `Link` component and that navigation to `"/"` effectively kills anything the current page/component is processing. This means the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler isn't called.

You've a couple options:

1. Add an `onClick` event handler to the `button` and call `stopPropagation` on the click event object to prevent it from bubbling up to the `Link`.
2. Add an `onClick` event handler to the `Link` component and call `preventDefault` on the click event object.

In either case the goal here is to prevent the immediate navigation from occurring, so the `add` and `update` handlers will need to issue an imperative redirect.

An example:

```
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AddContact = ({ addContactAction }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [{ email, name }, setState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevents default form action
    if (name === "" || email === "") {
      alert("Enter name and email!");
      return;
    }
    addContactAction(state);
    navigate("/", { replace: true }); // <-- navigate upon successful submit
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={add}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12 mt-5">
            <h2>Add Contact</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input
              type="text" 
              id="name"
              name="name"
              className="form-control" 
              placeholder="name"
              aria-label="name"
              value={name} 
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="email"
              aria-label="email" 
              value={email}
              onChange={changeHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-12 mt-3">
            <Link
              to="/"
              onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} // <-- prevent default link action
            >
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Since the tutorial taught me in `class` component and even though, I am aware, class component are not recommended by reactjs official documentation and they suggest us to use, functional components. I tried `window.location.href` instead of using `useNavigate` hook, as we cannot use hooks inside react class component, before I posted the question. I realised, changing the class to functional would be the best practice or we will caught up in such scenarios with no way out. However, going to try with `React.createRef()` to make myself familiarise with classes. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @CommonMan Fair enough. If you need to use class components and you need them to access the `navigate` function you can create a wrapper component or your own custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component. See on of my answers [here](/a/69902006/8690857) with example implementation and usage.

Comment: I have done this in class itself and I feel it as a hack and not a good quality, `<button className="btn btn-primary">Add</button> <Link to="/" type="hidden" ref={ this.redirect }></Link>` inside class `redirect = React.createRef();` and at end of event handler, `add = (e) => {`  I added, `this.redirect.current.click();` . I am grateful to you for making me to think. I will follow your guidance. I am going to learn and do the HOC as well, to see how it behaves and gives the same outcome. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @CommonMan Yeah, trying to use the React ref like that to simulate a click is a bit messy. I'd certainly push back if that was in a pull request.

Comment: I have followed your [answer: using HOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899955/problem-in-redirecting-programmatically-to-a-route-in-react-router-v6/69902006?noredirect=1#comment129791568_69902006) but I got `props, useNavigate, withRouter, navigate` are undefined in compiling errors. I did as, `<button {...props} navigate={navigate} className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>` and inside constructor, `const withRouter = EditContact => props => { const navigate = useNavigate(); };` finally, inside `update = (e) => {` handler, `this.props.navigate("/");`. What's my mistake?

Comment: @CommonMan This seems like something a bit off-topic for *this* question-answer pair, and a little more involved than can be resolved in the comments alone. The best option would be to create an entirely new post on SO for *that* specific issue (*you can reference the other SO answer you were trying to implement*) along with your [mcve] for it. If you do this feel free to ping me here in this thread in a comment with a link to your new post and I can take a look when available. A less ideal thing to do would be to create a *running* codesandbox of your code and link it here, and I can inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> If you are going to comment or suggest me to put a event handler on
> button instead of onSubmit could you please explain why it is and why
> not it will work being the present way of code.

As an event bubbles then there is a following sequence:

`button onClick => Link onClick (navigation occurs) => form submit`

When a navigation occurs DOM elements from prev page are removed with its event listeners and onSubmit is not called.

Comment: I am going to try that way... The above code are followed from a youtube video for DYI. There were some obsolete `router` concepts, which I managed to fix. Now, I am more curious that, how it were working for that youtube guy, with `react-router-dom` v.5.3