# How to extend a wrapped React.Component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899955/problem-in-redirecting-programmatically-to-a-route-in-react-router-v6) to get redirection functionality added to a `React` project I have been working on.

I have a class that is currently extended by several other classes; this parent class currently extends `React.Component`:

```javascript
class LoginForm extends Form {
   ...
}

export default LoginForm;
```

```javascript
class Form extends React.Component {
   ...
   ...
}

export default withRouter(Form);
```

This was working fine until I added this `withRouter` functionality on the component. I am now presented with the following error when the page loads:

```shellsession
Login.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value props => {
    _s();
    const params = (0,react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useParams)();
    cons...<omitted>... } is not a constructor or null
    at ./src/pages/Forms/Auth/Login.js (Login.js:8:1)
```

The code for wrapping the class export is:

```javascript
const withRouter = Wrapper => props => {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    return (
        <Wrapper
            {...props}
            navigate={navigate}
            params={params}
        />
    )
}

export default withRouter;
```

What do I need to do to be able to inherit this class? I do not want to refactor the whole site to use functional components, but we are using Router V6 - and I understand that using the hook is necessary. Is there a way to inject the property higher up to make this work?

Comment: It is deprecated. You can recreate it using the hooks version:

Comment: In React we don't extend other React Class components ***other than*** `React.Component`. See [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), it's considered very anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be able to extend something wrapped with a `withSomething` is for `withSomething` to return a class component.

Because of this, you won't be able to use any `useSomething` hooks in your `withSomething` function.

Without refactoring anything significantly, you should inherit from the base class and then use `withRouter` on your inherited class.

Alternatively, you could go back to React Router v5 and use their `withRouter` HOC

Answer (score 0):

The code for wrapping the class export is deprecated. You can recreate it using the hooks version like this:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

Or it can be written with an arrow function as you want it:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const ComponentWithRouterProp => (props) => {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

For more details, [check here](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-routes)

And finally,import your form component into loginForm eg `import Form from './Form'` into your LoginForm class component instead

Change your LoginForm code to something like:

```
import Form from './Form'
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
   ...
   // do something in your parent class
   <Form />

}

export default LoginForm;
```

and hence you should consider managing states as well.

Comment: And you will still just default export the `withRouter` function, right?

Comment: When implementing this method, I received this error: `Warning: The <LoginForm /> component appears to have a render method, but doesn't extend React.Component. This is likely to cause errors. Change LoginForm to extend React.Component instead.`

Comment: For the withRouter function is enough to get your routes to work. The warning says it all, you need to change your LoginForm to extend React.Component, check that your LoginForm class extends React.Component for it to work.

Comment: LoginForm extends Form, and then i have another component called `Form` that extends `React.Component`

Comment: You are doing it wrongly, you need to pass your states/props from one component to other eg LoginForm should receive props/states from the Form Component. Change class `LoginForm extends Form { ... }` to `class LoginForm extends React.Component { .. }` and just pass props/states from the Form component to the LoginForm.

Comment: Here is another example you can look at if you're not sure how to pass states from one component to another https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html. If you would prefer to manage states so easily, then, I would recommend using **redux**, a working example is here to get you started https://codesandbox.io/s/4xyi0

Comment: Namwanza: LoginForm extends Form, so when I create an instance of LoginForm, it will be a child of Form, and can therefore inherit the properties