# ReactJS : redirect function don't work (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

Good morning,

I just posted my question here because I can't find any answer anywhere... I'm simply trying to create a redirection with the "redirect" function of "react-router-dom" but it is completely ignored and I don't understand why ...

Imported function:

```
{ redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

My function:

```
switchView = () => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
        const url = state.signup === true ? '/signin' : '/signup';
        redirect(url);
        return {
            signup: !state.signup
        };
    });
}
```

My implementation:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" fullWidth={true} onClick={this.switchView}>
    {this.state.signup ? 'Connexion' : 'Inscription'}
</Button>
```

I redid the entire road management part...

Unfortunately I can't go through the useHistory hook because I'm going through a Component class extension. I don't know if you have a solution for this?

Do you have an idea ?

Thanking you.

Comment: which react-router-dom version you are using ?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0"

Comment: I think you can redirect to another component by using useNavigate hook in this verions

Comment: Unfortunately it's an extension of the "Component" class of "React", I can't use the hooks :/

Answer (score 1):

use `withRoute` hoc  for class components and access history object through props

Comment: This function is no longer available in version 6
I think I'm going to decide to stop using the "Component" class extensions. It's a shame, I find it practical.

Comment: @Ylann well i guess i found out ...this guy found an smart way to bring withRoute to react router v6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902006/18018440

Comment: @Ylann also your question is duplicate of the that question i guess

Comment: Yes indeed I hadn't seen it... But after trying it still doesn't work, it's incredible.

I'm going to change my way of working instead so that I can use hooks.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ylann FWIW React class components were effectively deprecated when hooks were released in [React 16.8.0](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) back in February 2019. Hooks are the current, and future (*at the moment*) of, React. I can't recall the last time I wrote a normal class-based React component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a class component and need to perform redirection using React Router, you can access the history object by wrapping your component with the withRouter higher-order component (HOC) from "react-router-dom."

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  switchView = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const url = this.state.signup ? '/signin' : '/signup';
    history.push(url);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      signup: !state.signup,
    }));
  };

  // Rest of your component code

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        size="small"
        fullWidth={true}
        onClick={this.switchView}
      >
        {this.state.signup ? 'Connexion' : 'Inscription'}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

This HOC injects the history prop into your component, allowing you to access the history object and perform the redirection.

Comment: No, it looks like it's no longer available in version 6.

Here is the error it returns to me:
`(imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'`

thanks anyway

Comment: yes, you are right. In version 6, the withRouter HOC has been removed. Instead, you can use the useNavigate hook to perform programmatic navigation within functional components, and for class components, you can use the useNavigate hook in combination with the useEffect hook.