# Event Listener on Navigation with react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-router, event-handling

I would like to add an event listener to a `navigate` event in react router v6. I have not found anything to it. Is there such a feature?

Edit: When the event is handled, I want to prevent the navigation and route the user to another destination, which depends on where he is comming from.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do this in RRDv6. You could create a custom router and history object so you can use [`history.block`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historyblockblocker-blocker). Perhaps at some point the `Prompt` component will be added back into v6 (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported).

Comment: If you need help with the custom router, my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/8690857) can help get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

You can [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) and `useEffect()`.

```js
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("url changed")
}, [location]);
```

Comment: Does this prevent the navigation? I want to use this to interrupt the navigate action and route to another url, depending where the user is comming from

Comment: No, this listens to changes. So please be more specific about what you need in your question.

Comment: Yeah thats my bad. Added the information

Comment: I’m looking for the same thing but BEFORE the navigation event occurs. This is for after. Is there a hook available for before navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with just using the navigate function once the location changes

```js
const location = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();
useEffect(() => {
   navigate("/home") // enter your route here
}, [location]);
```

this will look very ugly for the user tho

If you just want to block the navigation there is a new hook in react-router v6 called `useBlocker`, which can be used to display an alert when the specified boolean is true. Refer to [React Router Dom - v6 - useBlocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75135147/react-router-dom-v6-useblocker) issue here