# React Router Dom - v6 - useBlocker

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

As https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139 is finished and we got `useBlocker` in v6, did anyone got it to work?

This is what I got so far and pretty much I'm stuck with error I quite don't understand

in App.js I have my `BrowserRouter` and everything is wrapped inside

Also I used example from implementer's gists (I copy pasted)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useBeforeUnload, unstable_useBlocker as useBlocker } from "react-router-dom";

function usePrompt(message, { beforeUnload } = {}) {

let blocker = useBlocker(
  React.useCallback(
     () => (typeof message === "string" ? !window.confirm(message) : false),
  [message]
  )
);
let prevState = React.useRef(blocker.state);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
    blocker.reset();
  }
  prevState.current = blocker.state;
}, [blocker]);

useBeforeUnload(
     React.useCallback(
       (event) => {
         if (beforeUnload && typeof message === "string") {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.returnValue = message;
         }
      },
      [message, beforeUnload]
    ),
  { capture: true }
 );
}

function Prompt({ when, message, ...props }) {
    usePrompt(when ? message : false, props);
    return null;
}
```

And then within my component I called `Prompt` like this

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false)

    ...

    return (
        ...
        <Prompt when={showPrompt} 
                message="Unsaved changes detected, continue?" 
                beforeUnload={true} 
        />
    )
}
```

And on page load of `MyComponent` I keep getting error

```
Error: useBlocker must be used within a data router.  See 
    https://reactrouter.com/routers/picking-a-router.
     at invariant (history.ts:308:1)
     at useDataRouterContext (hooks.tsx:523:1)
     at useBlocker (hooks.tsx:723:1)
     at usePrompt (routerCustomPrompt.js:8:1)
     at Prompt (routerCustomPrompt.js:37:1)
```

Did anyone got `useBlocker` in new version to work?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is rather clear. In order to use the `useBlocker` hook it ***must*** be used within a component rendered by a Data router. See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router).

Example:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Prompt
      when={showPrompt} 
      message="Unsaved changes detected, continue?" 
      beforeUnload={true} 
    />
  );
}
```

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Root />}>
      {/* ... etc. */}
      <Route path="myComponent" element={<MyComponent />} />
      {/* ... etc. */}
    </Route>
  )
);

const App = () => <RouterProvider router={router} />;
```

Answer (score 6):

As I have a bit of a struggle with understanding how to get this `useBlocker` hook and `Prompt` component working, I will elaborate a bit more on code changes I had to do to get this working with `react-router-dom` version `6.10.0`.

Firstly, refer to the documentation of [Using v6.4 Data APIs In v6.4,](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.10.0/routers/picking-a-router#using-v64-data-apis) which suggests using the *new data APIs*, specifically `createBrowserRouter` instead of `<BrowserRouter>`.

As per documentation, the `<BrowserRouter>` based declaration does not *"support the data APIs"* which in turn results in `Error: useBlocker must be used within a data router`.

So in my app, I ended up replacing route declaration:

```ts
export default function App() {
  return (
    <YourProviders>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          // your routes
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </YourProviders>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(<App />);
```

**with**:

```ts
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Routes>
      // your routes
    </Routes>
  )
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <YourProviders>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </YourProviders>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(<App />);
```

Which in turn finally got the `Prompt` working as expected.