# react is not able to detect page leave event when goto other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to warn the user when some changes are made by the user and he tries to leave the page.
This is my react code it's working fine on page reload and or when try to close the tab. but when I try to goto another page this doesn't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const handleBeforeUnload = (e: any) => {
            console.log('123');
            if (hasUnsavedChanges) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = '';
                                return e.returnValue;
            }
        };

        // Attach the event listener
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
        };
    }, [hasUnsavedChanges]);
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49163569/1283345

Comment: this is for react-router v4 i am using v6

Comment: Checkout these for v6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75139360/1283345  and https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139

Comment: the beforeunload triggers when you hard navigate to another page, with react router the window is not unloading so the event is not dispatched that you are listening for now, I think @NooruddinLakhani s answer is what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the example and am getting the same error: useBlocker must be used within a data router. I tried to change it but doing something wrong as I am not a react expert.