# How to controling browser back button with react router dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been looking for this question and found it but they're using class components and react router dom v5

What i want is
When user click browser back button I'll redirect them to home page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 15):

Well after a long journey to find out how to do that finally i came up with this solution

```
window.onpopstate = () => {
  navigate("/");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## React-Router-Dom v6.0+ Routers

If you are simply wanting to run a function when a back navigation (*POP action*) occurs then a possible solution is to create a custom hook for it using the exported [`NavigationContext`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.ts#L236).

Example:

```js
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

const useBackListener = (callback) => {
  const navigator = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator;

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = ({ location, action }) => {
      console.log("listener", { location, action });
      if (action === "POP") {
        callback({ location, action });
      }
    };

    const unlisten = navigator.listen(listener);
    return unlisten;
  }, [callback, navigator]);
};
```

Usage:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useBackListener } from '../path/to/useBackListener';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

useBackListener(({ location }) => {
  console.log("Navigated Back", { location });
  navigate("/", { replace: true });
});
```

If using the `UNSAFE_NavigationContext` context is something you'd prefer to avoid then the alternative is to create a custom route that can use a custom history object (*i.e. from `createBrowserHistory`*) and use the normal [history.listen](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/8690857) for details.

### w/ Typescript

```js
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { NavigationType, UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";
import { History, Update } from "history";

const useBackListener = (callback: (...args: any) => void) => {
  const navigator = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator as History;

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = ({ location, action }: Update) => {
      console.log("listener", { location, action });
      if (action === NavigationType.Pop) {
        callback({ location, action });
      }
    };

    const unlisten = navigator.listen(listener);
    return unlisten;
  }, [callback, navigator]);
};
```

You can also use the `useNavigationType` hook if all you want is to know if a POP action occurred.

```js
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigationType,
  NavigationType
} from "react-router-dom";

const useBackListener = (callback) => {
  // Ref is used to handle any React.StrictMode double-mounting
  const initialRender = React.useRef(true);

  const location = useLocation();
  const navigationType = useNavigationType();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialRender.current && navigationType === NavigationType.Pop) {
      initialRender.current = false;
      callback({ location });
    }

  }, [callback, location, navigationType]);
};
```

## React-Router-Dom v6.4+ Data Routers

With the Data routers you can use the (*currently still used*) `router.subscribe` handler to replace `history.listen`. It is easily also abstracted into a custom if necessary. Note that `subscribe` is not currently part of the "public" API and exists similar to `NavigationContext` and `HistoryRouter` where they could be removed at any time. See this Github [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9422#issuecomment-1301182219) for more details/explanation.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
]);

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    router.subscribe((state) => {
      if (state.historyAction === NavigationType.Pop) {
        ....
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Example `state` value:

```
{
  actionData: null,
  blockers: {size: 0},
  errors: null,
  fetchers: {size: 0},
  historyAction: "PUSH",
  initialized: true,
  loaderData: {},
  location: {
    pathname: '/1',
    search: '',
    hash: '',
    state: null,
    key: 'oy0tkdth'
  },
  matches: [{…}, {…}],
  navigation: {
    state: 'idle',
    location: undefined,
    formMethod: undefined,
    formAction: undefined,
    formEncType: undefined,
    …
  },
  preventScrollReset: false,
  restoreScrollPosition: null,
  revalidation: "idle"
}
```

Comment: With Typescript version I'm getting 'Cannot find module 'history' or its corresponding type declarations.' (react-router v6)

Comment: Also after installing _npm i history_ I've had navigator.listen is not a function error message

Comment: @Eric It seems the RRD maintainers are making it more and more difficult to implement use cases like these. If all you need is to listen for `POP` navigation actions then the [`useNavigationType`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation-type) hook might be useful. It might also be a bit easier than the above. I'll need to play around to see what might still work with the later RRDv6 versions after 6.4.

Comment: My error: A history only accepts one active listener. I just put the `useBackListener` inside my component

Comment: @tonisives Yeah, it gets rather sketchy/dicey after RRDv6.4 with the Data Routers. I'll need to revisit this answer later when I have time to see what still works in later versions.

Comment: @tonisives Sorry for delay. I've updated with code that I was able to confirm still works through RRDv6.15.0, the latest current version as of this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a pretty robust solution for this situation, just using browser methods, since react-router-v6's API is pretty sketchy in this department right now.

I push on some fake history identical to the current route (aka a buffer against the back button). Then, I listen for a popstate event (back button event) and fire whatever JS I need, which in my case unmounts the component. If the component unmounts WITHOUT the use of the back button, like by an onscreen button or other logic, we just clean up our fake history using useEffect's callback. Phew. So it looks like:

```js
  function closeQuickView() {
    closeMe() // do whatever you need to close this component
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add a fake history event so that the back button does nothing if pressed once
    window.history.pushState('fake-route', document.title, window.location.href);

    addEventListener('popstate', closeQuickView);

    // Here is the cleanup when this component unmounts
    return () => {
      removeEventListener('popstate', closeQuickView);
      // If we left without using the back button, aka by using a button on the page, we need to clear out that fake history event
      if (window.history.state === 'fake-route') {
        window.history.back();
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: This works well, but has an issue that it can leave a ghost history entry. I'm have a *hamburger-menu* which contains links. If the *menu* is closed by cancelling it, it's fine. But if a **link** within the *menu* is clicked, by the time the *menu* unmounts, the **history.state** is no longer the `fake-route`. I'm going to see if I can add another listener then call `window.history.back()` and when that comes back, then navigate the user to their final destination. It feels like a lot of work for a simple thing, also I can't use simple links but rather have to redirect the user via JS.

Answer (score 2):

I used `<Link to={-1}>go back</Link>` and its working in v6, not sure if it's a bug or a feature but seems there is no error in console and can't find any documentation stating this kind of approach

Comment: This easiest answer needs to come up

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is how to use the browser's back button to navigate to a specific route.

Answer (score 0):

You can go back by using useNavigate hook, that has become with rrd v6

```html
import {useNabigate} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const goBack = () => navigate(-1);

    return (
        <div>
         ...
         <button onClick={goBack}>Go back</button>
         ...
        </div>
    )
}

export App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. This worked for me.

```
import { useNavigate, UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

const navigation = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator;
const navigate = useNaviagte();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      let unlisten = navigation.listen((locationListener) => {
        if (locationListener.action === "POP") {
          //do your stuff on back button click
          navigate("/");
        }
      });
      return(() => {
        unlisten();
      })
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution to prevent a path change

There is one detail you need to adjust if you don't want the path to be changed.
All of these solutions listened to a change of the path which was already performed, but there is no way to somehow prevent the default behavior. I came up with the following idea (`react-router-dom 6.11.0`):

```
import {NavigationType, useLocation, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {router} from "../router";
import {useEffect} from "react";

const MyComponent = () =>
{
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation()
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        navigate(location.pathname) // Just add the current path to the
                                    // history after the component did render. 
                                    // It will now be added once again to the history 
                                    // stack and if popped, the URL is the same as before, 
                                    // preventing your router to unmount this component.

  // Add your event listener as shown in the other solutions. 
  // You might also use e.g. window.popstate
      router.subscribe((state) => {
        if (state.historyAction === NavigationType.Pop) {
            // do work 
        }
    });

    }, []);




}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm on **rrd@6.8** and testing John's answer worked for me right away for a simple "GO back 1 page", no `useNavigate` needed:

```
<Link to={-1}>
    <Button size="sm">← Back </Button>
</Link>
```

So as a simple back button this seems to work without unexpected errors.

Comment: this simply goes back 1 page. navigate(-1) does the same thing. The question is how to use the browsers back button to go back to a specific route.