# How to run a function when user clicks the back button, in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I looked around and tried to find a solution with React router.
With V5 you can use `<Promt />`.
I tried also to find a vanilla JavaScript solution, but nothing worked for me.

I use React router v6 and `histroy` is replaced with `const navigate = useNavigation()` which doesn't have a `.listen` attribute.

Further v6 doesn't have a `<Promt />` component.

Nevertheless, at the end I used `useEffect` clear function. But this works for all changes of component. Also when going forward.

According to the react.js [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=React%20performs%20the%20cleanup%20when,running%20the%20effects%20next%20time.), *"React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts."*

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    // If user clicks the back button run function
    return resetValues();;
  })
```

Comment: Are you wanting to run a function specifically when a back navigation occurs, or when ***any*** navigation away from the page occurs. These are two different scenarios. What have you tried already? What didn't work, what was the issue? Why doesn't the `Prompt` component work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example A more correct solution would be to create a history object and use [`history.listen`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener) to listen for a POP action and handle accordingly.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese you are right. I just realized that this works ofcourse on going forward too. Please check updated question to see the reasons why solutions don't work in react router v6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `Prompt` component (*and `usePrompt` and `useBlocker`*) isn't [supported](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported) in `react-router-dom@6` but the maintainers appear to have every intention reintroducing it in the future.

If you are simply wanting to run a function when a back navigation (*POP action*) occurs then a possible solution is to create a custom hook for it using the exported [`NavigationContext`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L1410).

Example:

```
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

const useBackListener = (callback) => {
  const navigator = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext).navigator;

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = ({ location, action }) => {
      console.log("listener", { location, action });
      if (action === "POP") {
        callback({ location, action });
      }
    };

    const unlisten = navigator.listen(listener);
    return unlisten;
  }, [callback, navigator]);
};
```

Usage:

```
useBackListener(({ location }) =>
  console.log("Navigated Back", { location })
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-run-a-function-when-user-clicks-the-back-button-in-react-js]

If using the `UNSAFE_NavigationContext` context is something you'd prefer to avoid then the alternative is to create a custom route that can use a custom history object (*i.e. from `createBrowserHistory`*) and use the normal [history.listen](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/8690857) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please elaborate a bit more.  I use TypeScript and it throws an error on `navigator.listen(listener)`: `Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.`

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris That's a good question that I don't have a great answer for since I'm not very familiar with TS. I see that `navigator` is [typed](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L65) but doesn't include `listen`. It works though because the `navigator` object ***is*** an internally created `history` object. See [BrowserRouter](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L139-L169) for example. Perhaps you can create a union or extend the type that includes the `listen` function.

Comment: No problem! I just saved the hook as normal JavaScript file `.js` and it works fine! Further, I get that `action: "POP"`. This is a great answer! Thanks again!

Comment: As a temporary solution, you can do '(navigator as any).listen'