# Can not use history v5 with RRD v6, TS error Type 'BrowserHistory' is missing the following properties from type 'History': createURL, encodeLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, history.js

I'm currently using `React Router DOM v 6.8.1` and `history v 5.3.0`
I just followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74064963/react-router-dom-v6-prevent-transition-without-prompt/74065505#74065505)

But I get a TS error when trying to use `history` to `HistoryRouter`

```
<HistoryRouter history={history}>
   // code 
</HistoryRouter>

Type 'BrowserHistory' is missing the following properties from type 'History': createURL, encodeLocationts(2739)
```

[image]

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-2xdzbk?file=/src/App.tsx) on codesandbox

Comment: Has anyone find any fix on this?

Comment: I don't think so, I just dropped the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Change the `react-router-dom` version to 6.3.0 and it should work.
Else use a custom-made `router` function. Refer to the Screenshot how to use a `history` in `react-router-dom`

[image]

Comment: Please include your code directly instead of using a screenshot