# How to use BrowserHistory in Redux actions lavel react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-dom

I am new on react-router-dom v6. I want to use BrowserHistory in redux ations. Usually I wrapp my app with BrowserHistory and pass history object.

index.js

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

```
// Actions
export const createStream = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth

  try {
     const response = await addStream({ ...data, userId })
     dispatch({
       type: STREAM_ADDED,
       payload: { stream: response.data },
     })
    history.push('/')
  } catch (ex) {}
}
```

When user successfully create streams then I want to navigate user "/" path.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/8690857

Comment: I'd also recommend combining the solution in the link with [redux-first-history](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history) so you have a redux-connected router to also be able to dispatch navigation actions. I've not tested `redux-first-history` with RRDv6.4+ though, so there might be issues there.