# Can't redirect/navigate from axios interceptors in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to `'/login'` in axios interceptor while handling error.

My code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const instance = axios.create()

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  ... other code
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    console.log(error?.response.data)
    console.log(originalRequest._retry)

    if (
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      originalRequest.url === "http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/refresh-token"
    ) {
      localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");

      // I tried this
      return redirect("/login")

      // And also I tried this
      //router.navigate("/login");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
     ... other code
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I've tried two ways to do this:

- First: `return redirect`
- Second: `router.navigate`

But nothing works.

This how I defined router:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "*", Component: Root },
]);
```

Comment: Which React-router-dom version are you using ?

Comment: @MaulikPatel react-router-dom: 6.20.0, axios: 1.6.2

Comment: Do you only require to use redirect for the routing?

Comment: @DaniloFlores No, I just want to somehow navigate to 'login' from axios response interceptor

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here (but it is not the recommended way of doing things): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/4288706

Comment: @Anuja I've seen it and I tried router.navigate(targetPath, options) and it doesn't work

Comment: no you might need to create a `CustomRouter` with custom history, you can then export that `history` instance to navigate. @KirillStepankov

Comment: @Anuja But I did it. As I mentioned in the question I create `export const router = createBrowserRouter(...)` and then I used router: `router.navigate()`

Comment: @KirillStepankov check this code sandbox from original answer: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-v6-navigate-outside-of-components-90kf3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Comment: Kirill, @Anuja means something like this [answer](/a/70012117/8690857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect` utility only works in `Route` component's loaders/actions. I suggest importing the `axios` instance so the interceptors can be instantiated in scope with the `useNavigate` hook using a `useEffect` hook. If you like, the logic can be abstracted into a custom hook.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { instance as axiosInstance } from '../path/to/axiosInstance';

const useAxiosInterceptors = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      ... other code
    );
    
    const responseInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
    
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          if (originalRequest.url === "http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/refresh-token") {
            localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
            localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
    
            navigate("/login", { replace: true });
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
    
          if (!originalRequest._retry) {
            ... other code
          }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    // Return cleanup function to remove interceptors if necessary
    return () => {
      axiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      axiosInstance.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Use the `useAxiosInterceptors` hook in your route protection component.

Answer (score -2):

I used to implement React routing using useNavigate() in react-router-dom. You can refer below.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const instance = axios.create();

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  ... other code
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },

  (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    console.log(error?.response.data)
    console.log(originalRequest._retry)
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    if (
      error.response.status === 401 &&
      originalRequest.url === "http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/refresh-token"
    ) {
      localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");

      navigate("/login");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
     ... other code
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: eslint: React Hook "useNavigate" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. You can try const navigate = useNavigate(); line inside error handling callback function.

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: And you should use this method in a functional component. Or let's discuss further via Discord - danilo040117