# change the default localhost path react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

change the default localhost path. For example: http://localhost:3001/ by the path http://localhost:3001/home . I would like the when I launch npm start that I arrive directly on this path http://localhost:3001/ home . I tried modifying in the package.Json file, but it doesn't work. Thank you for help

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"}  />
          <Route element={<ViewParentCustomer />} >
            <Route path={RouteTypes.REDIRECT_HOME} element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path={RouteTypes.ROUTE_OUR_HISTORY} element={<OurHistory />} />
           
            
            <Route path={RouteTypes.ROUTE_COMMAND_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT} element={<ProtectedRoutes ><DetailCommand /></ProtectedRoutes>} />
            <Route path={RouteTypes.ROUTE_SIGNUP} element={<Registration />} />
            <Route path={RouteTypes.ROUTE_FORBIDDEN} element={<AccessForbidden />} /> 
          </Route>

        </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hey tony, watch this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a redirect to another route with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router)

Comment: the proposed solutions do not work react-router-dom, impossible to import IndexRoute

Comment: Can you include your package.json file, and any other routing/navigation code, as part of your [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution : `<Route path="/" element={ <Navigate to="/pastry" /> } />`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it like this:

```
<Redirect exact from="/" to="pastry" />
```

[Read more about redirecting here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

**UPDATE:**

You can use `Route`. Special thanks to [Kapobajza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049799/kapobajza):

```
<Route path="/" element={ <Navigate to="/pastry" /> } />
```

Comment: I can't import Redirect , react router dom doesn't offer it to me .  @StepUp

Comment: @tony https://stackoverflow.com/a/69872699/5049799

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually it doesn't work for what I'm looking for. I wish that when the application launches that I arrive directly at http://localhost:3001/pastry

Comment: @tony please, see my updated answer

Comment: I tried the answer you edited and thank you @StepUp, but I can't import Redirect with react-router-dom

Comment: the solution : <Route path="/" element={ <Navigate to="/pastry" /> } />  thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  <Route path={"/"} element={<Home/>} />
```

with

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />}/>
```

Imports:

```
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
```