# React-router-dom is not working with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

I'm building an web application besed on React and Vite. I also use `react-router-dom` to create a navigation into my app but when I go to the main page I've got this error in my browser's console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=67b79ac4' does not provide an export named 'Redirect'`

I'm trying to make a navigation into my React app with `react-router-dom`. Here is my `App.jsx` code :

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

import Header from "./routes/Header/Header";
import Home from "./routes/Home/Home.jsx";
import AboutMe from "./routes/AboutMe/AboutMe.jsx";
import Portfolio from "./routes/Portfolio/Portfolio.jsx";
import Socials from "./routes/Socials/Socials.jsx";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exace path="/about-me" component={AboutMe} />
          <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
          <Route exact path="/socials" component={Socials} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

And here is all my dependencies in the `package.json` file :

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.5.0",
  "sass": "^1.57.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
  "vite": "^4.0.0"
}
```

So can someone explain me why my navigation is not working and how can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: You're using code for RR v5 and below but you've installed v6. RR changed quite a lot when it advanced to v6. You'll want to take [a look at the upgrade documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6) and make those fixes to your code.

Comment: It looks like Vite is trying to import a specific version of the module, `/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=67b79ac4`, which does not contain the `Redirect` export.

Comment: React Router v6 has changed to use `Navigate` component instead of `Redirect`. You should do as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69872699/14426823. Note that the props for the `Route` component is also no longer `component=`; it is `element=` now

Answer (score 3):

Redirect was a feature of version 5 of `react-router-dom`. from your `package.json` file i can see you're using version 6. you have to do it like this `import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";`

you can learn more from their [official documentatuion](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)

Comment: I had tried redirect also, but it didn't work for me. I decided to use the Navigate component instead.

Answer (score 0):

Good question
might have something to do with

```js
<Route ***exace*** path="/about-me" component={AboutMe} />
```

might try to change it to exact. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your src directory update your index.js or main.js if using vite

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

import Route and Routes from react router dom then import your global assets in App.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';

import Header from "./routes/Header/Header";
import Home from "./routes/Home/Home.jsx";
import AboutMe from "./routes/AboutMe/AboutMe.jsx";
import Portfolio from "./routes/Portfolio/Portfolio.jsx";
import Socials from "./routes/Socials/Socials.jsx";
```

Then render

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element= {<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/about-me" element= {<AboutMe/>} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" element= {<Portfolio/>} />
        <Route path="/socials" element= {<Socials/>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Remember to update

```
<a href=""> to <Link to="">
```

for your nav links

Answer (score -1):

npm install react-router-dom localforage match-sorter sort-by

use this package for vite react router. It's works for me
here is the link
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Answer (score -3):

We'll be using Vite for our bundler and dev server for this tutorial. You'll need Node.js installed for the npm command line tool.

️ Open up your terminal and bootstrap a new React app with Vite:

npm create vite@latest name-of-your-project -- --template react

## follow prompts

cd 
npm install react-router-dom localforage match-sorter sort-by
npm run dev
You should be able to visit the URL printed in the terminal:

VITE v3.0.7  ready in 175 ms

➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).