# Changing behaviour of chrome back arrow button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am navigating the user to chat page when the user login but when the I click on back arrow[provided in image] then it won't let me to move back cause when I click on that it sends me to http://localhost:3000/login and again it will redirect me to http://localhost:3000/chat [because I am sending user to chat page if the token is available in localstorage]  so how can i make that when the user click on back arrow it will directly  navigate user to http://localhost:3000/
[image]

Routes

```
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route
          path="login"
          element={!token ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/chat" />}
        />
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/chat">
        <Route
          index
          element={token ? <ChatPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching almost a week and with the help of [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese)  answer and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868956/how-can-i-redirect-in-react-router-v6) 
I found my answer that I have to use **replace** in Navigate Hook to achieve what i want like

```
 const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route
          path="login"
          element={!token ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/chat" replace/>}
        />
        <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/chat">
        <Route
          index
          element={token ? <ChatPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace/>}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use redirect (REPLACE) navigation actions instead of navigate (PUSH) navigation actions when dealing with protected routes and authentication. To do this specify the `replace` prop on the `Navigate` component. This will more cleanly maintain a history stack.

```
const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

return (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route
        path="login"
        element={token
          ? <Navigate to="/chat" replace /> // <-- Redirect
          : <Login />
        }
      />
      <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path="/chat"
      element={token
        ? <ChatPage />
        : <Navigate to="/login" replace /> // <-- Redirect
      }
    />
  </Routes>
);
```

History stack example:

| User/UI Action | Nav Action | Stack |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | ["/"] |
| Click link to chat | PUSH "/chat" | ["/", "/chat"] |
| Auth redirect | REPLACE "/login" | ["/", "/login"] |
| User logs in, token updates | REPLACE "/chat" | ["/", "/chat"] |
| Click browser back button | POP | ["/"] |