# How to make when opening the website to load the page /Home not / in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Now when I opening the website he load http://localhost:3002/ but here I have only NavBar.

```
    function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <img src={header} className="Header-Image" alt="header" />
          <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Container>
              <Navbar.Brand href={"/Home"}>Далгъчев Транс ЕООД</Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
              <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                  <Nav.Link href="/Home">Начало</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="/Logistic">Логистика</Nav.Link>
                  <NavDropdown title="Услуги" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Автомобилен транспорт</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                      Въздушен транспорт
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Железопътен транспорт</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Контейнерен транспорт</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.5">Транспорт със собствени автомобили</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </NavDropdown>
                  <Nav.Link href="/Request">Заявки</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#contacts">Контакти</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
          </Navbar>
        </div>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Logistic" element={<Logistic />} />
          <Route path="/Request" element={<Request />} />
          <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I want when I openning the website to load http://localhost:3002/Home ..?

```
    function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
         <header className="App-header">
            <p>Автомобилен транспорт</p>
            <Container fluid className='Header-text'>
              
              <Row>
                <Col className='text'>

                  Автомобилната спедиция на "ДЪЛГЪЧЕВ ТРАНС ЕООД" е отдел с ключово значение за фирмата. Той е създаден с цел постигане на оптимални транспортни решения, предлагайки разнообразен автопарк, гъвкавост на възможностите за транспорт с фокус върху максималната удовлетвореност на нашите клиенти.

                  Нашата приоритетна стратегическа цел е качество на най-високо ниво на предлаганите от нас услуги. Ние предлагаме възможността да отделите време за важните моменти в живота като оставите всичко в нашите ръце.

                </Col>
              </Row>
     </Container>
              </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

**This is App function:**
[image: /]

**This is Home function:**

[image: /Home]

Is there a way when opening the website to route load the function /Home ?

Comment: check if this helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72242936/14718856

Comment: Just make the `/` route render a Navigate element that redirects there.