# Active styling is correctly applied to a nested Route but not on the parent default path=”/” in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect a Route on my default page with  to render content from another component and have both nav elements active. If I create a nested Route on any other page except the default route, both the main nav element and the nested nav element are active; however, when I try to apply the same logic to the default home page, only nested page nav element is active.

For example, the following works where when gallery and a nested route is selected

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="gallery" element={<Gallery />} >
       <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="projects" />} />
       <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
       <Route path="HtmlCss" element={<HtmlCss />} />
       <Route path="javascript" element={<Javascript />} />
       <Route path="ux" element={<UX />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="accessibility" element={<Accessibility />} />
</Routes>
```

However, when the nested Route is under the default path="/", it does not work.

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Gallery />} >
       <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="projects" />} />
       <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
       <Route path="HtmlCss" element={<HtmlCss />} />
       <Route path="javascript" element={<Javascript />} />
       <Route path="ux" element={<UX />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="accessibility" element={<Accessibility />} />
</Routes>
```

Is there any way to make the second version work?

===

UPDATE:
Also tried useRoutes, with no desire effect

```
const aboutRoutes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <About />,
    },
    {
      path: "/gallery",
      element: <Gallery />,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <Navigate replace to="projects" /> },
        { path: "projects", element: <Projects /> },
        { path: "HtmlCss", element: <HtmlCss /> },
        { path: "javascript", element: <Javascript /> },
        { path: "ux", element: <UX /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "accessibility",
      element: <Accessibility />,
    },
  ];

  const galleryRoutes = [
    {
      path: "about",
      element: <About />,
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Gallery />,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <Navigate replace to="projects" /> },
        { path: "projects", element: <Projects /> },
        { path: "HtmlCss", element: <HtmlCss /> },
        { path: "javascript", element: <Javascript /> },
        { path: "ux", element: <UX /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "accessibility",
      element: <Accessibility title="this is Accessibility page" />,
    },
  ];
```

Visual for not working - undesired result:

[image: Not working - undesired result]

Visual for working - desired result:

[image: Working - desired result]

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677141/react-router-dom-navlink-isactive-not-working-well-for-url-with-i) seems related. From what I've gathered, this is intentional behavior with the root `"/"` route path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post had a solution to my question:
[How to set the DefaultRoute to another Route in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552601/how-to-set-the-defaultroute-to-another-route-in-react-router/43958016#43958016)

revised and working code:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/gallery" />}>
      <Route path="gallery" element={<Gallery />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="gallery" element={<Gallery />}>
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="projects" />} />
      <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
      <Route path="HtmlCss" element={<HtmlCss />} />
      <Route path="javascript" element={<Javascript />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```