# How to make something different than `/` the "default" route?

Tags: redirect, react-router

I’m learning react-router (version 6), and working through a tutorial, but there is one thing I cannot find in the docs.
I’m writing a simple app with (basically) two routes, `/a` and `/b`.  Both pages should have some common elements like a header and a footer, so I set them up as nested routes of `/`, which defines said header and footer.  However, I do not want the user to ever land on `/` – the “main page” of the app is `/a`.  This means that typing the `/` route in the browser’s address bar should immediately redirect the user to `/a`.
How to make `/` serve both as a parent route to `/a` and `/b` and redirect to `/a` if visited explicitly?

It seems that what I want is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29552601/1181665), but that one uses the `<Route>` component instide a `BrowserRouter`, and (following the v6 tutorial) I use `createBrowserRouter` instead.